# Tor over non-noetherian local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m,k)$ be a local ring and let $M$ be a finite torsion $A$-module.
Is ${\rm Tor}^A_1(M,k)$ finite over $k$?

I am aware that the conclusion holds for any finite $A$-module $M$ when $A$ in Noetherian,
a reference is e.g. Bourbaki Algebre X.103, Exemple 3.

Comment: If $M=k$. then your Tor is finite dimensional iff $m$ is finitely generated (you can compute the Tor explicitely)

Comment: No, you can have $m$ not finitely generated but $m=m^2$ (thus $m\otimes _Ak=0$ and $Tor_1(k,k)=0$).

Comment: In some more detail: $Tor_1^A(k,k)=m/m^2$, so the answer to the question is no because $m/m^2$ need not be finite-dimensional over $k$. (But on the other hand there are examples in which $m/m^2=0$ even though $m$ is not a finitely generated module, so Mariano's "iff" should be just "if".)

Comment: @Tom: This is a perfect answer, not just a comment :)

Comment: Thanks to Mariano and Tom, I wanted the finiteness to hold so I forgot to check the special cases  :)